# Copy/unload errors from Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When copying data from a Redshift unload, I see data that looks like this:

```
.8f3d4.}.c754. SX8133c6d03a5cf848bfe5c50..*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
$15126f9833...4afc1.H....17eae4a.@40d3ea17c99e7237c.L   ..1(3a2807093a2.G7.7f76c1..<.=.c9.e38cc6d7.t6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
..=.....5..c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PAR1..........^L.......                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
"
```

What is this data format and what is going on? How do I skip these lines? OR rather... why does the data look like this?

Most of my rows are fine. This is my unload command:

```
UNLOAD (
    'SELECT es.user_id,
       NULL::"unknown"           AS event_id,
       es."timestamp" AS es_ts,
       es.session_id,
       NULL::"unknown"           AS referrer_id
    FROM es
    WHERE es."timestamp" < \'2023-08-15 00:00:00\'::timestamp without time zone'
)
TO '<some_path>'
iam_role '<some role>'
FORMAT PARQUET MANIFEST ALLOWOVERWRITE PARALLEL ON MAXFILESIZE 1024 MB;
```

```
COPY core.go_prod_session_backup
FROM '<path>'
iam_role '<some role>'
CSV
```

Comment: You will need to post your UNLOAD and COPY commands to get any read on this

Comment: done. I changed my post

Comment: Can you post the COPY?  It needs to be for Parquet formatted files

Comment: done, added the copy command

Answer (score 0):

You are unloading in Parque format but specifying CSV for the COPY.  The file format is Parque so you need to specify Parque in the COPY command.